# Need help in the server.js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite

I have been trying to make a website for my school's eLibrary. I need to make a login page where if you go to `xyz.com/home` it will redirect you to `xyz.com/` (the login page). I tried to make it, but I am facing issues.

```js
const express = require('express');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Open SQLite database connection
const db = new sqlite3.Database('mydatabase.db', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to the database.');
  }
});

app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect('/home.html');
  }
  next();
}

app.get('/', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/login.html');
});

app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  // Simulate database query for authentication
  db.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], (err, row) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }

    if (row) {
      res.redirect('/home.html'); // Redirect to home.html upon successful login
    } else {
      res.redirect('/page.html'); // Redirect to page.html upon invalid credentials
    }
  });
});

// Redirect /home.html to /index.html
app.get('/home.html', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This isn't working - how can I do this?

Comment: what issues are you facing

Comment: when i do xyz.com/home i am not being redireced to xyz.com/

Comment: are you sure that you get nothing back from the db query, maybe your _row_ is not undefined and therefore you're not redirected to login. try console logging the row and see what you get

Comment: https://github.com/gugabo11/stack

Comment: Remember to put `/` as your _last_ route, not your first route. And on a sidenote, even if you're not going to template anything, use a templating engine for your view dir, so you can use ```res.render(`index.html`)``` instead of using the sendFile function.